# Access to fields in IF sentence in DAX in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax

When I use SUM for example the intellisense of the editor shows me the columns of my table but when I use IF or Switch I'm not shown any column.

In this example of If (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/es-es/documentation/powerbi-desktop-tutorial-create-calculated-columns/) the column between [] works fine but when I put my column between [] I have error

error if

[image]

Any idea please?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you are creating a measure while in the tutorial they are creating a calculated column. Measures and Calculated columns behave different, while creating a calculated column the expression you are using takes the context of each row so you can reference any column directly by `[Column]`.

However measures evaluate in different context so they need an [aggregation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg399192(v=sql.110).aspx) function to determine the value of your columns.

**EXAMPLE:** Calculated Column.

```
Is Red Calculated Column = IF([Color]="Red","Yes","No")
```

**EXAMPLE: Measures.**

```
Is Red Measure = IF(FIRSTNONBLANK([Color],0)="Red","Yes","No")
```

Note I used `FIRSTNONBLANK` aggregation function to access the `[Color]` column from a measure.

The above expression could not work for you depending on your measure, I only posted it for example purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
TotalHoras = SUMX(Horas;if(Horas[Tipo]="M";Horas[Duration]/60;Horas[Duration]))
```

Like @alejandrozuleta says Measures need an aggregation function to works